# rsh for windows 7

Tags: windows, shell-scripting

I am looking for rsh client for windows 7. It should be GNU.

I also can't run setup on that machine, so this file must be copied.

Reasons: I had a windows XP batch file with rsh commands that executed commands on a remote  machine.
I am not allowed to install the "Windows Services for Unix" package in my system. Therefor I am looking for an exe file that I could copy to my win7 machine and my batch file would be able to run without changes.

Comment: I found this perfect replacement:
http://www.ccs.neu.edu/home/bchafy/rsh_vista.html

Comment: As you found your answer yourself: post it as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 2):

I would consider using [Putty](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html), it should do what you want. I haven't used rsh in many years, but i suppose it should work as expected.

You can download the exe-file [here](http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/latest/x86/putty.exe)

Comment: If Hirschkaefer wants something to use from the command-line instead of interactively, maybe Plink is a better choice from the PuTTY suite of programs.

Answer (score 0):

You can install [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com) which will let you run GNU programs inside Windows. I used it on Windows 7 and it didn't ask for administrator permission. In cygwin you can install rsh or upgrade to openssh.

Answer (score 0):

I found this perfect replacement: ccs.neu.edu/home/bchafy/rsh_vista.html